# Quickest Way to Serve Small Amounts of Data to Client

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am trying to figure out the quickest way to transfer small amount of data quickly and often from a server to an iPod Touch over Wi-Fi.

My goal is to send data from the server to the client to draw two circles, so I am sending only a few bytes of data. I want it to be as close to real time as possible and hopefully be able to update the circles 60 times a second.

I was looking into WebSocket but I am unsure if this is the fastest method. Does anybody have any advice on how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Maintaining an open socket between client and server that you can just send data directly from server to client continuously without initiating a new request each time seems like your lowest overhead option.  You'll have to test to see if 60 updates/second is doable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in using a library/framework, there are some available for "realtime" communication between client and server.

Microsoft stack: SignalR - http://www.asp.net/signalr

Meteor (a little over the top for what you need): http://www.meteor.com/

Or you can read about Comet, which is kind of a blanket term for doing what youre proposing:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Hope this gives you somewhere to start!